# Wordpress Leverage browser caching Show how to fix & Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content Show how to fix

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, cache

Good afternoon , as the title says I have the following problems that I tried and cannot find a solution for , I already tried the different solutions people posted here in different topics .

So basically I have a website , I tested it`s speed here : https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Those 2 problems in my title are persistent and whatever I tried its not working:
1. I installed w3 super cache plugin but its not working .
2. I edited the httacces file and added this code :

```
    ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

But nothing works , looking for more help from you guys . thanks !